# How to order columns according to custom order?

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a two data frames `df` and `df2`. `df2` is a derivative data frame of `df`. They both look like below:

```
df <- structure(list(A = c(100, 0, 0, 0, 0), B = c(10, 10, 10, 10, 
10)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
    A  B
1 100 10
2   0 10
3   0 10
4   0 10
5   0 10

df2 <- structure(list(A_h1 = c(50, 33.3333333333333, 11.1111111111111, 
3.7037037037037, 1.23456790123457), A_h2 = c(21.9223593595585, 
28.0776406404415, 17.9805898398896, 11.5145576200828, 7.3737868649931
), A_h3 = c(13.5918399333808, 20.6783494527816, 15.7298106138376, 
11.9655073298858, 9.10204001665479), B_h1 = c(5, 8.33333333333333, 
9.44444444444444, 9.81481481481481, 9.93827160493827), B_h2 = c(2.19223593595585, 
5, 6.79805898398896, 7.94951474599724, 8.68689343249655), B_h3 = c(1.35918399333808, 
3.42701893861624, 5, 6.19655073298858, 7.10675473465406)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
       A_h1      A_h2     A_h3     B_h1     B_h2     B_h3
1 50.000000 21.922359 13.59184 5.000000 2.192236 1.359184
2 33.333333 28.077641 20.67835 8.333333 5.000000 3.427019
3 11.111111 17.980590 15.72981 9.444444 6.798059 5.000000
4  3.703704 11.514558 11.96551 9.814815 7.949515 6.196551
5  1.234568  7.373787  9.10204 9.938272 8.686893 7.106755
```

Now I'd like to join them and order the columns so that the first column within the group is the original column from `df`. So the output would look like that:

```
    A      A_h1      A_h2     A_h3  B     B_h1     B_h2     B_h3
1 100 50.000000 21.922359 13.59184 10 5.000000 2.192236 1.359184
2   0 33.333333 28.077641 20.67835 10 8.333333 5.000000 3.427019
3   0 11.111111 17.980590 15.72981 10 9.444444 6.798059 5.000000
4   0  3.703704 11.514558 11.96551 10 9.814815 7.949515 6.196551
5   0  1.234568  7.373787  9.10204 10 9.938272 8.686893 7.106755
```

However, I don't know the number of original columns nor their names, so the whole procedure of ordering has to take account for that. How can I achieve this?

Comment: This looks like `cbind(df$A, df2)`...

Comment: What is the logic here? Insert columns after every 3rd column, or are we matching by name - "match A with columns in df2 and place it one before"?

Comment: @Sotos, It's not, please check the expected output again.

Comment: @zx8754, the second one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find a common pattern between the names of `df` and `df2` that you can use to `match`. For the example shared you can remove everything after underscore.

```
newdf <- cbind(df, df2)
newdf[order(match(sub('_.*', '', names(newdf)), names(df)))]

#   A      A_h1      A_h2     A_h3  B     B_h1     B_h2     B_h3
#1 100 50.000000 21.922359 13.59184 10 5.000000 2.192236 1.359184
#2   0 33.333333 28.077641 20.67835 10 8.333333 5.000000 3.427019
#3   0 11.111111 17.980590 15.72981 10 9.444444 6.798059 5.000000
#4   0  3.703704 11.514558 11.96551 10 9.814815 7.949515 6.196551
#5   0  1.234568  7.373787  9.10204 10 9.938272 8.686893 7.106755
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a base R one-liner.

```
final <- cbind(df, df2)[order(c(names(df), names(df2)))]

final
#    A      A_h1      A_h2     A_h3  B     B_h1     B_h2     B_h3
#1 100 50.000000 21.922359 13.59184 10 5.000000 2.192236 1.359184
#2   0 33.333333 28.077641 20.67835 10 8.333333 5.000000 3.427019
#3   0 11.111111 17.980590 15.72981 10 9.444444 6.798059 5.000000
#4   0  3.703704 11.514558 11.96551 10 9.814815 7.949515 6.196551
#5   0  1.234568  7.373787  9.10204 10 9.938272 8.686893 7.106755
```

## Edit

Following the OP's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63033216/how-to-order-columns-according-to-custom-order/63033381?noredirect=1#comment111466177_63033381), here is a function to solve the new version of this problem.

> Unfortunetely, this sorts the results alphabetically. Please note that
> if columns in df would have `B, A` order the result should have `B, B_h1, B_h2, B_h3, A, A_h1, A_h2, A_h3` order.

```
fun <- function(X, Y){
  res <- lapply(names(X), function(i){
    j <- grep(i, names(Y))
    cbind(X[i], Y[j])
  })
  do.call(cbind, res)
}

fun(df, df2)
fun(df1, df2)
```

Comment: Unfortunetely, this sorts the results alphabetically. Please note that if columns in `df` would have `B, A` order the result should have `B, B_h1, B_h2, B_h3, A, A_h1, A_h2, A_h3` order.

Answer (score 1):

An option with `mixedsort` from `gtools`

```
cbind(df, df2)[gtools::mixedsort(c(names(df), names(df2)))]
#    A      A_h1      A_h2     A_h3  B     B_h1     B_h2     B_h3
#1 100 50.000000 21.922359 13.59184 10 5.000000 2.192236 1.359184
#2   0 33.333333 28.077641 20.67835 10 8.333333 5.000000 3.427019
#3   0 11.111111 17.980590 15.72981 10 9.444444 6.798059 5.000000
#4   0  3.703704 11.514558 11.96551 10 9.814815 7.949515 6.196551
#5   0  1.234568  7.373787  9.10204 10 9.938272 8.686893 7.106755
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try the code below

```
lst <- split.default(df2,gsub("_.*","",names(df2)))
idx <- match(names(df),names(lst))
do.call(cbind,lapply(seq_along(idx), function(k) cbind(df[k],lst[[idx[k]]])))
```

which gives

```
> do.call(cbind,lapply(seq_along(idx), function(k) cbind(df[k],lst[[idx[k]]])))
    A      A_h1      A_h2     A_h3  B     B_h1     B_h2     B_h3
1 100 50.000000 21.922359 13.59184 10 5.000000 2.192236 1.359184
2   0 33.333333 28.077641 20.67835 10 8.333333 5.000000 3.427019
3   0 11.111111 17.980590 15.72981 10 9.444444 6.798059 5.000000
4   0  3.703704 11.514558 11.96551 10 9.814815 7.949515 6.196551
5   0  1.234568  7.373787  9.10204 10 9.938272 8.686893 7.106755
```

---

If you try another example

```
df <- rev(df)
> df
   B   A
1 10 100
2 10   0
3 10   0
4 10   0
5 10   0
```

you will see the result

```
> do.call(cbind,lapply(seq_along(idx), function(k) cbind(df[k],lst[[idx[k]]])))
   B     B_h1     B_h2     B_h3   A      A_h1      A_h2     A_h3
1 10 5.000000 2.192236 1.359184 100 50.000000 21.922359 13.59184
2 10 8.333333 5.000000 3.427019   0 33.333333 28.077641 20.67835
3 10 9.444444 6.798059 5.000000   0 11.111111 17.980590 15.72981
4 10 9.814815 7.949515 6.196551   0  3.703704 11.514558 11.96551
5 10 9.938272 8.686893 7.106755   0  1.234568  7.373787  9.10204
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative from the `dplyr` package. Based on `df` and `df2` in the question, the code and the output is as follows.

```
library(dplyr)
df3 <- data.frame(df, df2) %>% 
      select(starts_with("A"), everything())
df3 


#    A      A_h1      A_h2     A_h3  B     B_h1     B_h2     B_h3
#1 100 50.000000 21.922359 13.59184 10 5.000000 2.192236 1.359184
#2   0 33.333333 28.077641 20.67835 10 8.333333 5.000000 3.427019
#3   0 11.111111 17.980590 15.72981 10 9.444444 6.798059 5.000000
#4   0  3.703704 11.514558 11.96551 10 9.814815 7.949515 6.196551
#5   0  1.234568  7.373787  9.10204 10 9.938272 8.686893 7.106755
```